# Windows 8.1 Wireless Ad-hoc Network Not Detected

Tags: windows, ad-hoc-network

I have three computers.

- First one runs Raspian and hosts an Ad-hoc wireless network.
- Second one runs Windows 8 and connects to the first computer's ad-hoc network just fine.
- Third one runs Windows 8.1 and doesn't list the ad-hoc network on the list of wireless networks nearby.

Is this a Windows 8.1 issue? Some sort of settings issue?

Comment: Is it only when 2nd PC is connected? Or even when nothing is connected Win8.1 can't see it?

Comment: Regardless of the state the second PC is in, the third one does not see the ad-hoc network.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Windows 8.1

There is [a workaround](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/windows-81-ad-hoc-not-showing/5d75d887-ff59-425e-a480-9f80ada63627) but it's a bit cludgy:

> Because the wireless network picker in Windows 8.1 doesn't show ad-hoc networks, connecting must be done by hand.
>   To see all networks in range, including ad-hoc, run this command in command shell (cmd.exe):
>
> `netsh wlan show networks`
>
> **SETUP**
>
> This must be done once per network.
>   go to "Network and Sharing Center"
>   click "Set up a new connection or network"
>   double click "Manually connect to a wireless network"
>   enter the SSID of the ad-hoc network (as shown by "netsh wlan show networks") into the "Network name" field
>   configure security settings accordingly
>   uncheck "Start this connection automatically" (important)
>   click "Next", then "Close"
>   Run this command (important):
>
> `netsh wlan set profileparameter <ssid> connectiontype=ibss`
>
> Replace  with the SSID of your network.
>
> **CONNECT**
>
> After setting up, run this command whenever you want to connect:
>
> `netsh wlan connect <ssid>`
>
> Replace  with the SSID of your network.
>   Hovering over WiFi icon in system tray will show the name of the network that you are currently connected to, even if it's an ad-hoc network (the network picker will not show it if it's ad-hoc). The name is also visible in "Network and Sharing Center" window.
>
> **DISCONNECT**
>
> To disconnect from the ad-hoc network: connect to a different network, turn off wifi, or run this command:
>
> `netsh wlan disconnect`
>
> **CLEANUP**
>
> To remove the network profile from Windows, run this command:
>
> `netsh wlan delete profile <ssid>`
>
> Replace  with the SSID of your network.